# Converting to function to noop

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

So I have this code:

```
#ifdef FEATURE 
void foo(void);
#endif //#ifdef FEATURE
main {
    #ifdef FEATURE
    foo();
    #endif //FEATURE
}
```

I'm just wondering if there is more elegant to write this. I was thinking about doing something like this

```
#ifdef FEATURE 
void foo(void);
#else 
static inline foo() {
}
#endif //#ifdef FEATURE
```

That way the compiler should just remove that bit of code out of there and keep the main code cleaner.
Just wondering if there is a better solution out there?

Comment: `static inline foo()` -> `static inline void foo(void)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#ifdef FEATURE 
void foo (void) {  }
#else
#define foo()
#endif //#ifdef FEATURE

int main () {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `{}` after the declaration?

Comment: @Barmar It is the definition. Just created the function to test.

Comment: I think the intent was that this should just be a declaration of a function defined in another translation unit.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I've created there just as example, but it will work the same if it is a declaration. And can be the static inline mentioned in comments. This method avoids the `#ifdef`s in `main`.

Comment: `#define foo()` could be problematic, ex. with a comma operator `int a = (foo(), 1);`. Put something inside, typically  `#define foo() ((void)0)` or `do{}while(0)`

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a better solution out there?

No. And the solution is perfectly fine and doesn't need anything better.

Some prefer to drop `inline` specifier as it is only a hint to the compiler and just `static void foo(void) {}`. (But `inline` specifier silences `-Wunused-function` warning on `gcc`, so I'll say use it).

Comment: just curious if there was a way to wrap it in a macro function.